# Сериализация и десериализация Java

Tags: java, сериализация, десериализация

Изучая сериализация и десериализацию на Java возник такой вопрос, могу ли я в один файл сохранить объекты двух разных классов? Если да, то пожалуйста опишите кратко как это можно сделать.

Comment: Поместите оба объекта в контейнер вроде `ArrayList<Object>`. Работайте с ним.

Comment: Создайте объект третьего типа, который хранит ссылки на объекты первого и второго типа. Работайте с ним.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять любое количество объектов без проблем. Вот набросал пример:

```
public class SerializationTest {
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  static class Some implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int a;
    private String b;
  }

  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  static class Other implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int a;
    private String b;
  }

  @Test
  public void serializationOfTwoObjects()
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      Some some = new Some(1, "2");
      Other other = new Other(3, "4");

      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream
        = new FileOutputStream("yourfile.txt");
      try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream
        = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(some);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(other);
      }

      FileInputStream fileInputStream
        = new FileInputStream("yourfile.txt");
      try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream
        = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)) {
        Some some2 = (Some) objectInputStream.readObject();
        Other other2 = (Other) objectInputStream.readObject();
        assertThat(some2.getA(), equalTo(some.getA()));
        assertThat(some2.getB(), equalTo(some.getB()));
        assertThat(other2.getA(), equalTo(other.getA()));
        assertThat(other2.getB(), equalTo(other.getB()));
      }
  }
}
```